# Elementary OS 5.1 Hera Screen Tearing

Tags: nvidia, games

I have NVIDIA GTX 1050 TI with proprietary driver version 440.59.

I got screen tearing when using 3D apps like Maya and Blender 3D. Same problem when playing videos with vlc or in Youtube.

I've tried follow some articles but no one can fix it.

Solution i've tried:

- Enabling **Force Full Composition Pipeline** in *Nvidia-Settings*. It seem this work. Screen tearing is disappear. But I'm playing DOTA 2 in this OS. Enabling this thing make the game stutters. It shows 60fps but it feel really like 20-40fps. 
  But, if i disabling this **Force Full Composition Pipeline**, the game play so smoothly on 60fps. And then the screen tearing happen again.

So, is there any solution? new solution?

EDIT: I have Fedora 31 too on my PC (Dual booting). With Pantheon DE on it, same nvidia driver version. **Force Composition Pipeline** Enabled. The game play smoothly and stable on 60 fps. No screen tearing too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't help with this, but have you checked out if anything on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting may be of help?

On a side note: How well does Pantheon work on F31, I was under the impression it didn't quite work in F31? I love the DE, but eOS has so many goddamn bugs, and the devs seem way more interested in making stuff they can slap a pricetag on, than actually fixing their shitty OS.

Comment: I've tried adding TripleBuffer inside xorg.conf and still not change. Maybe i will use Pantheon on Fedora for a while. 

Pantheon work really well on F31 like a charm. But still missing some function like date and time, user account. I'm really satisfied with it. Hope the Pantheon become more complete in Fedora. The performance is far better than EOS. Fluidity and smooth. Gaming is awesome, Rendering is faster.

Hope EOS can improve their performance someday. Not much stuttering in everything